# Regex to remove everything after gmail reply string

Tags: regex

```
This is my reply

On Wed, Jun 23, 2021 at 3:22 PM A User (User) <user@mygmailaccount.com>
wrote:
> hello this is my initial email.
>
>
```

I only want to be able to display my reply message and remove all previous responses.

I use the following regex expression, and it removes everything after "wrote:"

`\wrote.*$`

Which displays

```
This is my reply

On Wed, Jun 23, 2021 at 3:22 PM A User (User) <user@mygmailaccount.com>
```

I need an expression that will look for the "On" and "wrote:" and remove everything after it.

Comment: What if the message itself contains 'On' or 'wrote'?

Comment: `\w` is a meta escape...

Comment: @SagarV yes agree, which is why I was needing a qualifier for both.  The answer below worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the dot match a newline using for example an inline modifier `(?s)` and then first match On at the start of the string, and then match wrote: after matching a newline.

```
(?s)^\s*\bOn\b.*\nwrote:.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3YF9XI/1)

Or using a character class to match any char

```
^\s*\bOn\b[\s\S]*\nwrote:[\s\S]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HxOuVE/1)

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for me in python:

```
r'\s*\bOn\b.*wrote:.[\s\S]*$'
```